# Is it possible to limit method execution to a certain class?

Tags: java

I was wondering if it was possible to only allow a certain set of classes to execute a function.

I have a method: `setPermission()`
This method should only be called by certain classes throughout the project.

Some people suggested having the calling class pass in `this`, referencing the current object and ensuring it is an `instanceof` an allowed class. But any class could pass in an instance of an allowed class an so this seems to be an poor solution.

I also stumbled across `Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();` however I am led to believe this is quite an expensive operation.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: This seems like a design smell. Usually you only expose methods as public that you want to *be* publicly accessible, and everything else  is marked private, protected or internal.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem? It's pretty hard to prevent *arbitrary code* from invoking a given method (even "private methods") if it really desires to do so .. as such, understanding the requirements and usage may lead to better solutions/suggestions.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Are you trying to protected yourself from calling this from a place where you should not call it? Or are some security constraints behind this?

Comment: Well, it is for a software defined networking security modification. Third party developers can develop internal Java modules that basically slot into the controller (part of the SDN that calls the shots) and for security reasons it would be counter productive for these modules to have access to certain classes and their methods

Comment: Críostóir Ó Catháin sounds to me like you're looking for OSGi (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi). Third party developers should write bundles and with OSGi you can restrict capabilities of their bundles. Put your attention to: "Security
The layer that handles the security aspects by limiting bundle functionality to pre-defined capabilities."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) (one that doesn't have any methods):

```
public interface Permissible {}
```

Then have the classes that are allowed to call your method implement it, then change the parameter type of your method to this interface:

```
public static void myMethodForObjectsThatHavePermission(Permissible obj) {
    //
}
```

Comment: That's no better than the `instanceof` solution, though. A caller can just pass in an instance of it (even with an anonymous inner class).

Comment: @DavidConrad It's way better than `instancof`, because problems are found at *compile* time, whereas `instanceof` will cause a *runtime* problem, which are far harder to find and fix. Regarding circumvention, if a programmer in the team uses the strategy you mention, sack him from the team - he's not a team player. An regarding other circumvention "tricks", there's always reflection, with which you can pretty much do what you want, so making such claims is moot. Makeing your code compile -time safe given huge benefits and is one of the cornerstones and strengths of the java language.

Comment: Using an interface still has the same fundamental problem acknowledged by the OP: "But any class could pass in an instance of an allowed class [or interface] an so this seems to be an poor solution."

Comment: What do you mean with the "team player"? What if this was part of a library used by some random person ? I would say there is something wrong with the architecture of his solution. A way better approach would be to enforce permission checking before returning an object of the class containing setPermission() to an "authenticated" client

Comment: You are not providing any security crucial data or logic to 'some random person' within your libraries, aren't you? So if it is public lib and this topic is about 'prevention' but someone is using it not as documented, he will get into trouble right?

Comment: @enterbios if it's a public library, I would use reflection to check if a field exists.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to enforce it that can't be worked around, but you could have most of your functionality on one class, `setPermission()` on a subclass, and make clients get an instance of your class via a factory method that is declared to return the parent class, but actually returns an instance of the subclass. That way, code that is supposed to call `setPermission()`, and knows about it, can do a downcast and call it, and all other users of the class won't even see it.

```
public class Service {
    protected boolean permission = false; 

    protected Service() {
        /* control creation */
    }

    public static Service getService() {
        return new RealService();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        /* the public API side of the service */
    }
}

public class RealService extends Service {
    protected RealService() {
        /* control creation */
    }

    public void setPermission(boolean permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }
}
```

A legitimate caller can do this:

```
public class Legitimate {
    public void method() {
        Service service = Service.getService();
        RealService real = (RealService) service;
        real.setPermission(true);
    }
}
```

However, if all the legitimate callers can be put into the same package, and all the rest are outside the package, then package-private access (no access modifier) for `setPermission()` would be sufficient.

This doesn't prevent malicious callers from getting around the restriction, but it does avoid people calling setPermission without realizing they're not supposed to, because setPermission wouldn't show up in autocompletion (intellisense) in an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're looking for OSGi (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi). Third party developers should write bundles and with OSGi you can restrict capabilities of their bundles. Put your attention to: "Security The layer that handles the security aspects by limiting bundle functionality to pre-defined capabilities." Here is a thread discussing your case: [Managing access to OSGI bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261358/managing-access-to-osgi-bundles)